# What can I punch?

Tags: home, substitute-tool

I'd like to punch something like this to destress:

[image]

I don't have one though. What general household items can I put together to allow me to do the same?

---

***Moderator note:*** "Mind hacks" are off-topic here. This question is about a [substitute-tool](/questions/tagged/substitute-tool) for a punching dummy, not about reducing stress. Please answer accordingly. *Thank you!*

Comment: Have you tried searching at all? [A google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=diy+punching+dummy) results in a bunch of instructions.

Comment: @Alex I've seen those but they require a lot more than general household items.

Comment: To those who have voted to close as "this is a mind hack"... I do not think so. Perfectly good #lifehacks question here. +1

Comment: Most commercial punching bags are simply canvas cases containing a large amount of tightly packed rags, sometimes with a bit of something heavy packed in the middle for added weight.

Comment: well can i know the purpose of punching like this?

Comment: You can always *come at me bro*

Comment: i read destress as distress, and this question went in a whole other direction o_O

Answer (score 10):

A 50 lb bag of dog food inside a sleeping bag or large laundry bag may provide a satisfying impact without significant risk of hand injury.  Failing that, a well-stuffed bag of laundry can also sub for a heavy bag.  Either one can be upgraded with a printed photo or drawing of a face taped on.

Comment: Edit suggested to remove "If you have a dog..." I got very sad until I read you were suggesting dog food, which the OP can surely purchase whether he has a dog or not.

Comment: CAREFUL!  I have done this and had the bag rupture, spilling dog food all over the place.  And it was a well built bag too.

Comment: @Daniel Hence why I suggested putting the dog food inside another bag -- that will contain the mess if the bag ruptures.

Comment: +1 for good answer, \*facepalm\* to me for not reading all of it.

Answer (score 7):

Following are two different types of punching *bags*. To mount them onto a base, you could use a similar method as mentioned before, with a PVC pipe and an old parasol stand, or maybe you even have a small (but bigger than a gallon) water tank and could fill that one up with sand.

#### Probably simplest punching bag

1. Get a rice bag.
2. Fill it with rice if it isn't already.

Do not punch without gloves. You could still wrap it with duct tape to make it even more durable.

#### Using old clothes or grocery bags

1. Get a laundry bag **or** (at least) two garbage bags.
2. Fill it with (shredded) old clothes (hoodies, jeans, etc.) **or** stuff it with a lot of crumpled up plastic grocery bags.
3. If you use garbage bags I recommend covering the bag with one or two layers of duct tape. To be sure, you can also wrap the laundry bag with duct tape.

To protect your wrists, also use gloves when punching this bag.

---

Be creative! Use this as inspiration. You can basically use any type of bag or stuffing. It's just a matter of how hard you like your punching bag, or in this case, punching dummy.

Answer (score 4):

If it does not have to be human-shaped, you can just prop up your mattress against a wall. Since it's soft, you can punch it out to your heart's content. A wall also does nicely, I've found the pain of your fist crashing into hard concrete quickly relieves any frustration.

Comment: An ordinary mattress won't protect your fist, and punching a wall is surely prone to creating hand injuries.

Comment: Or holes in the wall. https://ilikedogsblog.files.wordpress.com/2015/06/punch.jpg

Comment: "I've found the pain of your fist crashing into hard concrete quickly relieves any frustration." So true!

Comment: Or may increase frustration, depending on the situation! :)

Answer (score 3):

1. Roll up a carpet onto a PVC pipe (or onto a tall wooden cylinder, if you like hard center) and secure it with some duct tape.
2. Take a lot of duct tape and cover the whole thing with duct tape to make it tighter and more durable
3. As a base, use a big bag of sand or an old parasol stand if you have one around. Whatever you use, make sure it is well joined.

As a reference, see [this YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4gzW6_mXlhc).

Answer (score 3):

I used to know a martial arts expert. He turned the newel post at the bottom of his stairs into a target by padding it heavily. He used it both for kicking and punching. He would attack it every time he went past.

Answer (score 3):

A large pile of dough is perfect for this activity.

Satisfying smack, safe soft material, and then the opportunity to enjoy a meal afterwards; pizza dough would be preferable for the post-workup meal.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Most commercial punching bags are simply canvas cases containing a large amount of tightly packed rags, sometimes with a bit of something heavy packed in the middle for added weight. you could achieve something similar using old clothes, towels etc for filling, and a large bag/sack (e.g. hessian sack, sleeping bag) to hold them.

Answer (score 1):

You could get an old camping tarp and fill it with bags of flour, or even some dirt.  It will have a good weight to it, but won't be overly solid, and if you don't have the tarp, looks like you can pick one up at Wal-mart for $10 - $15 (in the US anyway).

If you go the dirt route, you would have the added benefit of the manual labor which could potentially help to de-stress as well, if you're that kind of person. The problem with dirt, however, is if you end up getting rocks in it.  Might hurt to punch

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can punch two pillows combined. However , it may not be useful for training. Maybe just for reducing the stress level.